# PHPExcel white background

Tags: background, phpexcel

I am importing an Excel spreadsheet into a web page using the PHPExcel libraries:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

it works but it overrides my page background to white. Every other element on the page it's formatted correctly according to my CSS but not the background. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default background for an Excel cell is white, so you probably want to change that. I don't know where you're setting the page background in the first place, unless you've modified the HTML Writer to do so, or changed it in the Excel file (you don't indicate which); but try setting a default cell background for the worksheet:

```
$objPHPExcel->getDefaultStyle()->applyFromArray(
    array(
        'fill' => array(
            'type'  => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
            'color' => array('argb' => 'FFFFFF00')
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: Sorry my fault, what I mean is that the import code is modifying the background color of my <body> in the DOM. The pointer to the CSS file is locate at the top of my current page.

Comment: What import code? The HTML Writer creates its own body background, style so where are you setting it?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I think I am confused. I am inserting my spreadsheet into a div in my web page using the $objWriter. All styles are defined in a CSS file and they are shown correctly except the background color of my web page that should be blue and it is white. Is $objWriter overriding my BODY background color?

Comment: All styles should be defined in the markup generated by the HTML Writer.... The writer creates full HTML markup, including html, head and body tags, inline styles, etc; because it is rendering a full HTML page of markup; not a block to be embedded in a div

Comment: I see, thank you for the explanation. The page look OK except the body color. Could you tell me how to insert the background color for the body in the  HTML Writer? Sorry if i am testing your patience!

Comment: Unless you want to modify the HTML Writer code, try doing what I suggested and changing the workbook's default background colour after loading it, and before saving as HTML

Comment: thank you Mark, your comments point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Baker point me in the right direction to answer my own question, this is the reason why I marked his answer as the accepted one.

To fix my problem I have added the following lines:

```
$objWriter->generateStyles(false);
echo $objWriter->generateSheetData();
```

after:

```
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'HTML');
```